# How to correctly write a condition in view Django?

Tags: django, django-views

The meaning of the program is to select analogues from the list and link them. I bind all values.
I think the problem is in the wrong `if`. How to fix it

My `view`:

```
def editpart(request, id, **kwargs):

    if request.method == 'POST':
        part.name = request.POST.get("name")
        part.description = request.POST.get("description")

        analogs = Part.objects.all()
        for analog_zap in analogs:
            analog = analog_zap.analog
                if Part.objects.filter(analog_analog = analog):
                        part.analog.add(analog_zap.id)
```

My `model`:

```
class Part(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField('Название', max_length=100)
    analog = models.ManyToManyField('self', blank=True, related_name='AnalogParts')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm just going to assume you have gotten a `part` object before trying to assign the following:

```
part.name = request.POST.get("name")
part.description = request.POST.get("description")
```

Whether this was intended to update the "*retrieved part object*" or not, I'd recommend that you have instead two fresh variables to collect the info from the `post` `request`, then update the `part` object with these if any related info were found in the database.

```
name = request.POST.get("name")
description = request.POST.get("description")
```

As for the real issue here... Not sure I'm understanding your question much but I do see a problem with one of your `if statements` though. You have:

```
for analog_zap in analogs:
     analog = analog_zap.analog
          if Part.objects.filter(analog_analog = analog):  # problem here...
               part.analog.add(analog_zap.id)
```

As you've posted:

```
class Part(models.Model):
     name = models.CharField('Название', max_length=100)
     analog = models.ManyToManyField('self', blank=True, related_name='AnalogParts')  # right here...
```

The `Part` `model` has a field called `analog`, not `analog_analog`: maybe you meant `analog__analog`. But maybe you should try checking by: `if Part.objects.filter(analog__pk=analog.pk)` or `if Part.objects.filter(analog__in=[analog]).distinct()`.

Furthermore, what you might want to do is to check if something `exists`, so add `.exists()` to the end of `if Part.objects.filter(analog__pk=analog.pk)`. Example:

```
if Part.objects.filter(analog__pk=analog.pk).exists():
     ...
```

Looking like:

```
for analog_zap in analogs:
     analog = analog_zap.analog
          if Part.objects.filter(analog__pk=analog.pk).exists():
               part.analog.add(analog_zap.id)
               
               # update the name and description here as well with the values retrieved from the post request
               part.name = name
               part.description = description
```

You could try that.

**UPDATES**

What worked in this context is:

```
Part.objects.filter(analog__in=[analog_zap]).distinct()
```

Comment: now error 'ManyRelatedManager' object has no attribute 'pk'

Comment: Have you tried `Part.objects.filter(AnalogParts__in=[analog]).distinct()` instead?

Comment: Cannot resolve keyword 'AnalogParts' into field. Choices are: KitParts, analog, brand, description, id, images, images0, images1, images2, name, number

Comment: My bad... I think It should be `analog` and not `AnalogParts`: `Part.objects.filter(analog__in=[analog]).distinct()`.

Comment: `Field 'id' expected a number but got <django.db.models.fields.related_descriptors.create_forward_many_to_many_manager.<locals>.ManyRelatedManager object at 0x7f91a5049850>.`

Comment: Not sure why you're getting that now. But one last try at `analog__in=[analog.id]`. Since this error is saying it's expecting an `id`. Just try `analog.id` instead of `analog`.

Comment: it work with `Part.objects.filter(analog__in=[analog_zap]).distinct():`, but still bind all values.
Thank u <3

Comment: Okay good. I'll just update the answer to put what worked for you. :-)